# Django EmailMessage reply_to object not passing through to headers

Tags: django, django-views

So, I've tried every possible combination and cannot get the `reply_to` object to pass to the headers; even if I hard-code the reply_to email address.  The form works other than that without any issues.  Thank you for your help

**versions**

```
Django==1.10.1
sendgrid==3.6.3
sendgrid-django==4.0.4
```

**view**

```
def index(request):
    form_class = FooterForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            fullname = request.POST.get('fullname')
            phone_number = request.POST.get('phone_number')
            email_address = request.POST.get('email_address')
            message_content = request.POST.get('message_content')
            subject = 'Contact Information Submitted from Trust and Beneficiary Advocates'
            from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
            recipient_list = 'info@trustadvocates.com'
            bcc = 'charles@studiorooster.com'
            ctx = {
                'title': 'Trust and Beneficiary Advocates',
                'subject': subject,
                'fullname': fullname,
                'phone_number': phone_number,
                'email_address': email_address,
                'message_content': message_content
            }

            message = get_template('email_forms/contact_form_email.html').render(Context(ctx))
            msg = EmailMessage(
                subject,
                message,
                from_email,
                [recipient_list],
                [bcc],
                reply_to=['helpme@helpme.com']
            )
            msg.content_subtype = 'html'
            msg.send()

            return redirect('/thank-you/')

    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', {
        'form': form_class, 'title': 'Trust and Beneficiary Advocates'
    })
```

**reply_to combinations tried**

```
reply_to=['helpme@helpme.com']
headers={'Reply-To': 'helpme@helpme.com'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks ok - using `reply_to=['helpme@helpme.com']` should work in Django 1.8+.

It looks like you've hit [this bug](https://github.com/elbuo8/sendgrid-django/issues/50) in sendgrid-django. You could try applying the fix in [pull request 51](https://github.com/elbuo8/sendgrid-django/pull/51/files) (it only supports a single reply-to address but in your case that looks ok), or you could switch to another service to send your emails.

Comment: Thank you.  That worked for me.  I wasn't sure of the steps involved to patch an existing package and I wanted to do it with `pip`.  My question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281009/patch-django-site-package-from-a-pull-request-using-pip explains how to do it.