# Patch Django Site Package From a Pull Request Using Pip

Tags: python, django, git, pip

I need to apply [pull request 51](https://github.com/elbuo8/sendgrid-django/pull/51/files?diff=unified#diff-2197cf74593a047b34e5abd03c298fc7) to a locally installed Site Package in my Django project but I am not sure how it should be done without applying directly to the local library.

Is there a way to add reference to the pull request in `requirements.txt` or git config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't modify installed packages.

Fork the project and apply the PR to your fork, then point requirements.txt at the fork.

Comment: That Worked!!  Once I forked the repo and applied my changes; I needed to add it as a requirement in `requirements.txt` as you mentioned, but through trial and error, I found out that with Python3.5 adding the package like `-e git+https://github.com/studiorooster/sendgrid-django.git#egg=sendgrid-django` didn't work, I needed to add it like `-e git+https://github.com/studiorooster/sendgrid-django.git#egg=branch_or_commit` - then after uninstalling the previous package, did a simple `pip install -r requirements.txt` and boom...all fixed.